# xdebug not stopping at breakpoints for webpage

Tags: php, phpunit, localhost, wamp, xdebug

When I run my unit tests on phpunit, the breakpoints are being stopped at.  But when the same functions are being run on a webpage, it doesn't stop. It used to stop at breakpoints but a couple days ago, it just started running through them. Anyone got ideas on what could have cause this?

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

That it what my php.ini file currently looks like.
Using WAMP server

Comment: `php.ini` vs `php-cli.ini` could be one possible problem

Comment: @Havelock Should they be the same? Also have xdebug helper added to my browser.

Comment: What breakpoints are you talking about

Comment: @marvelownz in some setups both ini's are available and yes, they should be the same, or at least the xdebug part ;)

Comment: @Havelock Yea they are both the same for the xdebug part